# Does kaa has an api to list all registered end-point/devices for an application?

Tags: kaa

Does kaa has an api to list all registered end-point/devices for an application by application ID? Or do we have to parse the registration logs to get a unique list of end points? Thanks.

Comment: Kaa has APIs to get groups under an application and get endpoint devices     under groups. I think these two APIs will help you to find devices for an application.

Answer (score 0):

As commented @Pete you can list all registered end-point/devices for an application. Every Kaa application, when created, becomes a member of the default group all. See [Using endpoint groups](https://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/latest/Programming-guide/Key-platform-features/Endpoint-groups/#using-endpoint-groups) documentation. Also look at corresponding Server REST APIs [Grouping](https://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/latest/Programming-guide/Server-REST-APIs/#resource_Grouping) and [Profiling](https://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/latest/Programming-guide/Server-REST-APIs/#resource_Profiling) documentation sections.